# Expansion of the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(k(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the expression $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(k(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})$, I used chain rule to expand the given expression into $k(x)\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + k'(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, it  is correct.

Comment: Except it's the product rule $(vw)' = v'w + vw'$ you're using, not the chain rule $(v(w(x)))' = v'(w(x))w'(x)$.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, your answer is correct.